# Nesting blochspheres in tikzpictures using the blochsphere package

Tags: tikz-pgf, nesting

I am using the blochsphere package (see [1](https://ctan.org/pkg/blochsphere?lang=de)) and I want to nest it in another tikzpicture, to work with several blochspheres. The manual tells one to put "nested=true" in the settings for `\begin{tikzpicture}`. Unfortunately there are many errors, even when using the blochsphere example, given in the manual - which I use to provide a MWE:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node [fill=red]{
\begin{blochsphere}[radius=1.5 cm,tilt=15,rotation=-20,nested=true]
\drawBallGrid[style={opacity=0.3}]{30}{30}


\drawGreatCircle[style={dashed}]{-60}{0}{0}
\drawGreatCircle[style={dashed}]{60}{0}{0}

\drawRotationLeft[scale=1.3,style={red}]{-60}{0}{0}{15}
\drawRotationRight[scale=1.3,style={red}]{60}{0}{0}{15}

\node at (-0.8,1.9) {\textcolor{red}{\tiny $J_{12}(t)$}};
\node at (1.1,1.8) {\textcolor{red}{\tiny $J_{23}(t)$}};

\labelLatLon{up}{90}{0};
\labelLatLon{down}{-90}{90};
\node[above] at (up) {{\tiny $\left|1\right>$ }};
\node[below] at (down) {{\tiny $\left|0\right>$}};
\labelLatLon[labelmark=false]{d}{15}{90};
\node at (d) {\color{gray}\fontsize{0.15cm}{1em}\selectfont $60^\circ$};

\labelLatLon[labelmark=false]{d2}{5}{78};
\end{blochsphere}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

All I changed was the first and last two lines of code and the `nested=true` in the third line. One error is (e.g.)

`! Undefined control sequence.\tmp ->\endgroup \draw[current plane,on layer=back,opacity=0.3] (\agamma -\... \drawBallGrid[style={opacity=0.3}]{30}{30}`

In the case of my personal blochsphere I get those as well as other errors like `missing number treated as zero` etc.
Could someone help me make the blochsphere package work to nest in another tikzpicture?

Thank you!

Comment: Looking at the package code then I don't think that a nested blochsphere should be inside a node.  Try it without the surrounding node.

Comment: A workaround would be to store the blochshpere in a savebox.

Comment: I just discovered that the same question is also over at Stackoverflow where it has an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73306947/9303652

Comment: Oh it must have been moved or something. Thank you!

Comment: If your goal is to draw multiple of these things and position them relative to each other then you may be interested in the capability of the tikzmark library to position scopes as if they were nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue with using the `nested=true` key on the `blochsphere` environment.  In a normal blochsphere environment, the initialisation is done before the tikzpicture is started.  With a nested one, the initialisation is done after the tikzpicture is started.  For most of the relevant code, that doesn't matter.  However, one part does need to be in place *before* the tikzpicture is started and that is the layers.  So you need to have the following lines in your preamble:

```
\pgfdeclarelayer{back}%
\pgfdeclarelayer{front}%
\pgfsetlayers{back,main,front}%
```

Once this is in place, a blochsphere environment can be used directly inside a tikzpicture environment.  It does **not** need to be inside a node (and, indeed, *should* not be used inside a node).  But it can be included inside a scope, and that scope can be repositioned to change the location of the blochsphere.  It may be that simple translations are sufficient, as in the following code, but if you want a more sophisticated positioning syntax then consider the development version of the [`tikzmark`](https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark) which allows you to define "anchors" on a scope in a similar fashion to nodes.

Full code follows.  There were a few other minor issues which I've fixed in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/653567/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blochsphere}

% These lines are needed when using the `nested=true` option
\pgfdeclarelayer{back}%
\pgfdeclarelayer{front}%
\pgfsetlayers{back,main,front}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\begin{blochsphere}[radius=1.5 cm,tilt=15,rotation=-20,nested=true]
% The next line is automatically included when not nesting
% but needs to be here when nesting
\drawBall
\drawBallGrid[style={draw,opacity=0.3}]{30}{30}

% These two commands only take 3 arguments (including the optional style)
\drawGreatCircle[style={dashed}]{-60}{0}%{0}
\drawGreatCircle[style={dashed}]{60}{0}%{0}

\drawRotationLeft[scale=1.3,style={red}]{-60}{0}{0}{15}
\drawRotationRight[scale=1.3,style={red}]{60}{0}{0}{15}

\node at (-0.8,1.9) {\textcolor{red}{\tiny $J_{12}(t)$}};
\node at (1.1,1.8) {\textcolor{red}{\tiny $J_{23}(t)$}};

% There were a few extra ;s in these lines
\labelLatLon{up}{90}{0}
\labelLatLon{down}{-90}{90}
\node[above] at (up) {{\tiny $\left|1\right>$ }};
\node[below] at (down) {{\tiny $\left|0\right>$}};
\labelLatLon[labelmark=false]{d}{15}{90}
\node at (d) {\color{gray}\fontsize{0.15cm}{1em}\selectfont $60^\circ$};

\labelLatLon[labelmark=false]{d2}{5}{78}

\end{blochsphere}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(4,0)}]
\begin{blochsphere}[radius=1.5 cm,tilt=15,rotation=-20,nested=true]
\drawBall
\drawBallGrid[style={draw,opacity=0.3}]{30}{30}

\drawGreatCircle[style={dashed}]{-60}{0}%{0}
\drawGreatCircle[style={dashed}]{60}{0}%{0}

\drawRotationLeft[scale=1.3,style={red}]{-60}{0}{0}{15}
\drawRotationRight[scale=1.3,style={red}]{60}{0}{0}{15}

\node at (-0.8,1.9) {\textcolor{red}{\tiny $J_{12}(t)$}};
\node at (1.1,1.8) {\textcolor{red}{\tiny $J_{23}(t)$}};

\labelLatLon{up}{90}{0}
\labelLatLon{down}{-90}{90}
\node[above] at (up) {{\tiny $\left|1\right>$ }};
\node[below] at (down) {{\tiny $\left|0\right>$}};
\labelLatLon[labelmark=false]{d}{15}{90}
\node at (d) {\color{gray}\fontsize{0.15cm}{1em}\selectfont $60^\circ$};

\labelLatLon[labelmark=false]{d2}{5}{78}

\end{blochsphere}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two blochspheres inside a single tikzpicture]

Answer (score 2):

I think the `nested` option has another meaning which I don't quite understand. In your code above add a `;` after the enclosing `\node` macro and delete the `nested` option (or set it to `false`).

However, it is not a good idea to nest `tikzpictures` (and the `blochsphere` is essentially one). If you really want to place complicated stuff inside Ti*k*Z nodes, you should probably use a `savebox` for storage:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{blochsphere}
    
\newsavebox{\blochA}
\begin{lrbox}{\blochA}
\begin{blochsphere}[radius=1.5 cm,tilt=15,rotation=-20]
\drawBallGrid[style={opacity=0.3}]{30}{30}

\drawGreatCircle[style={dashed}]{-60}{0}{0}
\drawGreatCircle[style={dashed}]{60}{0}{0}

\drawRotationLeft[scale=1.3,style={red}]{-60}{0}{0}{15}
\drawRotationRight[scale=1.3,style={red}]{60}{0}{0}{15}

\node at (-0.8,1.9) {\textcolor{red}{\tiny $J_{12}(t)$}};
\node at (1.1,1.8) {\textcolor{red}{\tiny $J_{23}(t)$}};

\labelLatLon{up}{90}{0};
\labelLatLon{down}{-90}{90};
\node[above] at (up) {{\tiny $\left|1\right>$ }};
\node[below] at (down) {{\tiny $\left|0\right>$}};
\labelLatLon[labelmark=false]{d}{15}{90};
\node at (d) {\color{gray}\fontsize{0.15cm}{1em}\selectfont $60^\circ$};

\labelLatLon[labelmark=false]{d2}{5}{78};
\end{blochsphere}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[fill=red!10] at (0,0) {\usebox{\blochA}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! May I ask what exactly is the difference between nesting and using a safebox? At first glance it seems to be exactly the same, with the safebox only being a placeholder for some code.

Comment: @manuel459 A savebox kind of "locks" its contents. It has already been typeset, but is only printed at the position where you put `\usebox`. In this regard, it is not just a placeholder. On the other hand, if you place the `blochspere` environment inside a node, it will only be typeset at this point in time where a lot of other things are already defined by the surrounding `tikzpicture` etc. which then obviously results in errors. I am not able to explain it better, sorry.

Comment: From looking at the code, the `nested` option removes the enclosing tikzpicture environment meaning that all the commands are fine in the outer tikzpicture. I really think that it is just the enclosing node that is the problem, but I can't test it right now.